# Datarow System.IndexOutOfRangeException

Tags: sql, database, c++-cli

trying to access the table row but but it becomes IndexOutOfRangeException the database only has one table and 2 rows

```
SqlConnection ^ conDatabase =
        gcnew SqlConnection(L"Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFileName='C:/Users/pcusername/Documents/Visual Studio 2010/Projects/nv/nv/project/project/vn.mdf';Integrated Security='True'");
    SqlCommand ^ cmdDatabase =
        gcnew SqlCommand(L"SELECT * FROM Table;", conDatabase);

    dataSet1 = gcnew DataSet("Table");
    SqlDataAdapter ^ sda = gcnew SqlDataAdapter();


    sda->SelectCommand = cmdDatabase;
    dataSet1->Tables;

    DataRow ^ recEmployee = dataSet1->Tables[1]->Rows[0];/*System.IndexOutOfRangeException*/
```

Comment: This is C++/CLI not C++. Please tag your question appropriately.

Comment: Thanks for correcting sorry about that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
DataRow ^ recEmployee = dataSet1->Tables[0]->Rows[0];
```

Since c++ is zero indexed based, the first table will be at index zero, not one.  It is also a good idea to check that the table and row exist before trying to retrieve them.  Make sure that that you actually get any results back from the database.  IF you aren't getting anything, it may be the semicolon in your sql statement.  Some connections won't allow semi colons in your sql.

Comment: Thank you but one more question please. System.IndexOutOfRangeException at DataRow ^ recEmployee = dataSet1->Tables[0]->Rows[0]; its the data row this time.

Comment: @user3541906 Do you know for sure you have any rows?  Did you check the row count in the debugger?

Answer (score 0):

C++ collections are zero-based, so you should use `Tables[0]` to return the first table, not `Tables[1]`